# Can't get specificity to override boostrap CDN link element

Tags: css

Having trouble overriding specificity on a element with bootsrap CND

Trying to get the text red on this codepen but something wrong with my syntax or specificity?

```
 #wrapper#yourdiv#portfolio_hover a{color:red;}
```

Whole pen is over here:

http://codepen.io/Satearn/pen/BWxZBb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not wise to style the anchor tag because on careful inspection the `.folio-text` element has its own styling that override its parent (anchor). Style the child class `.folio-text` as follows:

```
.folio-text{
  color:red ;
}
```

[codepen here](http://codepen.io/repzeroworld/pen/gmzxEW)

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the text incorrectly.  If you want to change the base color ( not hovered over use the following :

```
#wrapper #yourdiv .folio-text{color:red }
```

If you only want to change color on hover you can use :

```
#wrapper #yourdiv .folio-text:hover{color:red }
```